# ngspice error: too many nodes connected to instance

Tags: simulation, ngspice

I'm getting the following error from ngspice:

```
too many nodes connected to instance
```

The netlist and circuit I'm modeling are shown below. Each bulk is tied to the source, so I have the sources and bulks of each transistor at the same node.

Where is the error in my netlist?

```
* Differential pair
*** Netlist
VDD VDD   0 dc=2 ac=0
IDD VDD  VA dc=15u ac=0
M1   VA  VA   0   0 .model nmosfet w=9u l=5u
M4   VD  VA   0   0 .model nmosfet w=27u l=5u
M2   VC  VB  VD  VD .model nmosfet w=4.5u l=5u
M5   VF  VE  VD  VD .model nmosfet w=4.5u l=5u
M3   VC  VC VDD VDD .model pmosfet w=50u l=5u
M6   VF  VC VDD VDD .model pmosfet w=50u l=5u
CLD  VF   0 10p
*** Model statements
.model nmosfet nmos vto=400m kp=200u lambda=10m tox=5n
.model pmosfet pmos vto=400m kp=50u lambda=10m tox=5n
*** Commands
.op
.end
```

[image]

ngspice errors:

```
Warning: Model issue on line 7 :
  m1 va va 0 0 .model nmosfet w=9u l=5u ...
too many nodes connected to instance
Warning: Model issue on line 8 :
  m4 vd va 0 0 .model nmosfet w=27u l=5u ...
too many nodes connected to instance
Warning: Model issue on line 9 :
  m2 vc vb vd vd .model nmosfet w=4.5u l=5u ...
too many nodes connected to instance
Warning: Model issue on line 10 :
  m5 vf ve vd vd .model nmosfet w=4.5u l=5u ...
too many nodes connected to instance
Warning: Model issue on line 11 :
  m3 vc vc vdd vdd .model pmosfet w=50u l=5u ...
too many nodes connected to instance
Warning: Model issue on line 12 :
  m6 vf vc vdd vdd .model pmosfet w=50u l=5u ...
too many nodes connected to instance
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have a syntax error. When you instantiate a transistor, don't include `.model` as part of the line, just provide the model name.

`M1   VA  VA   0   0 .model nmosfet w=9u l=5u`

becomes

`M1   VA  VA   0   0 nmosfet w=9u l=5u`